# Dynamic Variable Selectors in JQuery

Tags: jquery

If I have a varibale that changes on certain conditions how do I select it using Jquery selectors?

```
var id = 2
alert($('.'+id+ ' .title').val());
```

Comment: Please clarify the question. What you have looks fine, aside from the fact that the variable is called "id" but you're using a class selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem here is that you are starting a classname with a number. class names must start with an _ a - or a letter.

switch up your structure so its:

```
var id = 2
alert($('.' + 'title' + id).val());
```

or some variation so that id starts with an underscore, dash, or letter:

```
var id = 2
alert($('._' + id + ' .title').val());
```

Comment: The selector in your first example would be `..title2`.