# How to create a function with brackets that accepts parameters (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Say that I wanted to create a function in jQuery like this:

```
DisplayRandomNumber({ min: 0, max: 100, displayAt: 'someID' });
```

that would create a random number between `min` and `max`, and display it at the ID referenced in `displayAt`.

How is this done?

Sorry if this is ridiculously simple, I just am not sure how this is done yet. Probably found elsewhere, but not showing up on the stackOverflow search.

Comment: What does the google say?

Comment: The `{...}` just denote an object literal, it's still a normal function. You have to create a function that accepts one argument (which is supposed to be an object) and then you access the object's properties. Please read the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) to learn more about objects. Maybe it's clearly if you see the above example written as `var config = { min: 0, max: 100, displayAt: 'someID' }; DisplayRandomNumber(config)`.

Comment: `function DisplayRandomNumber(params){ console.log(params.min); }`

Comment: How to do what? Define functions? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: What does this have to do with jQuery?  You are creating a function in *JavaScript*.

Comment: for the displayAt part (jquery only). I wasn't sure if I had to use $.fn.extend for something like this. Only reason

Comment: See [Dynamic Variable Selectors in JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8349250/218196).

Comment: @Lexica98 The simplest way would be the second comment by Felix Kling. Using an object and then passing it to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Without JQuery:

```
function DisplayRandomNumber(options) {
    var rand = options.min + Math.random() * (options.max + 1 - options.min);
    document.getElementById(options.displayAt).innerHTML( Math.floor(rand) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
  DisplayRandomNumber: function(obj) {
    var dispaly = $("#" + obj.displayAt);
     ...
 }
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.fn.extend/

Answer (score 0):

```
function DisplayRandomNumber(options) {
    var defaults = { min: 0, max: 100, displayAt: 'someID' };
    options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    var min = options.min;
    var max = options.max;
    var displayAt = options.displayAt;
}
```

See [`jQuery.extend()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)

Answer (score 0):

I Think you will like to do something like this :

```
function DisplayRandomNumber(obj){
var lb = obj.min;
var ub = obj.max;
obj.displayAt =  Math.floor(Math.random()*ub)+lb;
alert(obj.displayAt);
}


DisplayRandomNumber({ min: 1, max: 100, displayAt: 'someID' });
```